# SQL subtracting data based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following SQL table which contains following columns and data:

| ITEM_ID | CUST_ID | AMOUNT | TYPE | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 3477.88 | RAW | null |
| 13 | 34 | 1400.33 | REFINED | 12 |
| 15 | 34 | 300 | REFINED | 12 |
| 17 | 41 | 4500 | RAW | null |
| 18 | 41 | 1500 | REFINED | 17 |
| 23 | 41 | 3500 | REFINED | null |
| 24 | 41 | 6000 | RAW | null |
| 25 | 41 | 1460 | REFINED | 24 |

Rules for getting the results:

1. REFINED amount is sum of all REFINED type amounts
2. UNREFINED amount is (sum of RAW where type is RAW and PARENT_ID is null) - (associated REFINED amounts where PARENT_ID is the ID of RAW type).
3. Results must be grouped by customer (CUST_ID, REFINED_AMOUNT, UNREFINED_AMOUNT)
4. RAW type can have 0 or more REFINED amounts
5. REFINED type can be standalone (without PARENT_ID)

So what I am trying to achieve is to get result like this:

| CUST_ID | REFINED_AMOUNT | UNREFINED_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 1700.33 | 1777.55 |
| 41 | 6460.00 | 7540.00 |

How the result is calculated:
For customer 34:

1. REFINED amount = 1400.33 + 300 (both are REFINED)
2. UNREFINED amount = 3477.88 - (1400.33 + 300) = 1777.55

For customer 41:

1. REFINED amount = 1500 + 3500 + 1460 = 6460.00
2. UNREFINED amount = [4500 - 1500] + [6000 - 1460] = 7540.00

I have hard time creating necessary SQL to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `conditional sum` is all you need, the following arrives at your desired results:

```
select cust_Id,
    Sum(case when type='refined' then amount else 0 end) Refined_Amount,
    Sum(case when type='RAW' and PARENT_ID is null then amount end) 
    - Sum(case when type='refined' and parent_id is not null then amount else 0 end) Unrefined_Amount
from t
group by cust_id
```

Comment: . . You might want `else 0` so the difference is not `NULL` if no rows match the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CUST_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'REFINED' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) REFINED_AMOUNT,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN TYPE = 'RAW' AND PARENT_ID IS NULL THEN 1 
             WHEN TYPE = 'REFINED' AND PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN -1
             ELSE 0 
           END * AMOUNT
          )  UNREFINED_AMOUNT
FROM tablename
GROUP BY CUST_ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b5a508ee23282769c489a21be6be0f4).

Comment: I gave you up but I cant accept both of the answers here. Your solution worked very well too, but he managed to submit answer first. I hope you dont mind :)  Thank you for your answer